# python3: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script. It runs ok in python2, but when I run it in python3, I get this error:

```
name = r.content.translate(None, "\n \t/\"'")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

the line that assigned `r` is this:

```
r = requests.get('10.10.10.10/test_' + name, verify=True)
```

how can I fix this problem ?
I need my script to run in python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```py
name = (r.content.translate(None, "\n \t/\"'".encode())).decode
```

Comment: thanks, but that created a new problem couple of lines later: `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`. The line that triggert the error is: `m = re.search('test-(\d+.\d+.\d+)-\d+.patch' , name)`

Comment: @MartinVegter Oh, ok, You should do `name = (r.content.translate(None, "\n \t/\"'".encode())).decode()` to get the string, or `name = str(r.content.translate(None, "\n \t/\"'".encode()))`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what translate function needs. you must check the documentation. 
But looking at the error may the following might fix the error.

```
name = r.content.translate(None, b"\n \t/\"'")
```

name is then of type `bytes`. so you need to convert it back to type `str`.

So you can try

```
name = str(r.content.translate(None, b"\n \t/\"'"))
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed that particular problem. But it created a new one couple of lines later: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`. The line that triggered this error is: `r = requests.get(baseurl + name, auth=(username, password), verify=True)`.

Comment: updated the answer. updated the type from bytes to str